# Why is stdin closed when using a heredoc as input to shell

Tags: shell, heredoc

I'm a bit confused by this

```
$ bash <<EOF
  read -p 'This will not work' input
EOF
```

because

```
$ cat script
read -p 'This will work fine' input
$ bash script
This will work fine
```

What's the difference? It appears to be a standard behavior because `ash` behaves exactly the same way.

---

Based on the answers provided so far, I suspected (and then confirmed) that the following works. I think this is actually what I wanted to do all along, but the `<()` syntax is always one that I forget exists.

```
$ bash <( cat <<EOF
  read -p 'This works' input
EOF
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `read` is a bash builtin, it inherits stdin from `bash` as is mentioned above. In the first case `bash` has a here document as stdin (or more professionally, File Descriptor 0) and there's nothing available for `read` to read.
`read` only reads from stdin (`fd0`) while in the second case, `bash` opens another file descriptor rather than stdin to read scripts from `script`, which does *NOT* conflict with stdin passed to `read`, so that `read` can work as intended.
You can try this to test out.

```
$ bash << EOF
ls -l /proc/$$/fd
EOF
```

and

```
$ cat script.sh
ls -l /proc/$$/fd
$ bash script.sh
```

The difference is apparent if you compare the outputs from samples bove.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple simultaneous `stdin` per process, so the here document passed as input to `bash` cannot contain a `read -p`.

With `bash script`, the running `script` is a subprocess of the Bash shell and there is no concurrent `stdin` to `read`, so it will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the `read` command inherits its standard input from the `bash` process that executes it.

In the first example, that means the here document that actually *contains* the `read` command. Depending on how much of the document `bash` has already read (usually all of it), nothing remains for `read` to read, and so it exits with a non-zero exit status.

In the second example, `bash` opens the named file on a *different* file descriptor. `read` still inherits its standard input from the `bash` process, but this time `bash` hasn't read from it at all, so the `read` command gets the next available line. Standard input here is the terminal, so `read` blocks until the user enters a line.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to write the interactive commands to a temporary file, then source the temporary file:

```
cat <<'_EOF_' >/tmp/$$.sh
read -p 'This is an interactive command, please enter a string: ' STRING
_EOF_
# Command in temporary file get executed here
source /tmp/$$.sh
echo "STRING= '$STRING'"
```